# Show that the triangles have the same center of gravity.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:** The points $D,E,F$ divides the $\triangle ABC$ so that  $\vec{AB}=3\vec{AD}, \ \vec{BC}=3\vec{BE}$ and $\vec{CA}=3\vec{CF}.$ Show that the triangles share the same center of gravity.

I've drawn the triangles and the vectors, but for the life of me I'm really bad at thinking in vectors and linear algebra. Any general tips on how to think in situations like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of proof: If you pick an origin $O$ (any origin will work; for instance $A$ is allowed, as is the center of gravity of the large triangle, since even though you don't really know exactly where that is yet it does have some definite position), then the center of gravity of the two triangles are $\frac{\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC}}{3}$ and $\frac{\vec{OD} + \vec{OE} + \vec{OF}}{3}$.

Now express $\vec{OD}, \vec{OE}$ and $\vec{OF}$ in terms of $\vec{OA}, \vec{OB}$ and $\vec{OC}$, insert it into the center of gravity of the small triangle, and see that you do indeed get the same result.

Comment: Can the origin be picked outside of the triangle?

Comment: @Parseval Sure. Just be sure that once you've picked one, you use the same one for everything.

Comment: Ok, I'll use it now to first prove the formulas for the center of gravity of a triangle.

Comment: The thing is, I cant use the formula $$\vec{OG} = \frac 13 (\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC})$$ without proving it first. ($G$ is the centroid).

Comment: If you want to prove that, you must first have a definition of centroid to work with. In mathematics, definitions are the bread and butter, while theorems are merely there to tell us how definitions of different concepts play along. In some books, what you have there _is_ the definition of the centroid. What is yours?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ and let $0$ be the origin. Then we know that $\vec{OG} = \frac 13 (\vec{OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec{OC})$. To prove that $G$ is the centroid of $\triangle DEF$ it's enough to prove that $\vec{OG} = \frac 13 (\vec{OD} + \vec{OE} + \vec{OF})$. Now we have:

$$\vec{OD} + \vec{OE} + \vec{OF} = \vec{OA} + \vec{AD} + \vec{OB} + \vec{BE} + \vec{OC} + \vec{CF} = 3\vec{OG}$$

Hence the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The center of gravity for $\triangle ABC$ is an only point $G$ which satisfies $\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}=0$. Since we have $\vec{GD}=\frac{2\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}}{3}, \vec{GE}=\frac{2\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}}{3}, \vec{GF}=\frac{2\vec{GC}+\vec{GA}}{3}$, $\vec{GD}+\vec{GE}+\vec{GF}=\vec{GA}+\vec{GB}+\vec{GC}=0$. Thus they share same center of gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{AB}=a$ and $\vec{AC}=b$.

Also, let $M$ and $N$ be centers of gravity of $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta DEF$ respectively.

Thus, $$\vec{AM}=\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\right)=\frac{1}{3}(a+b)$$ and
$$\vec{AN}=\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}(\vec{DE}+\vec{DF})=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{1}{3}b-\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{2}{3}b\right)=\frac{1}{3}(a+b)$$
and we are done!